# parse_expr fails when zeta is used as a variable name in larger expression

Tags: python, sympy

I'm using sympy 1.3 with python 3.6.6 and trying to use `sympy_parser.parse_expr` to create a sympy expression from a string. Doing this with `'zeta'` works fine, but using `'zeta + 1'` gives a type error:

```
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 1023, in as_terms
    coeff, _term = term.as_coeff_Mul()
TypeError: as_coeff_Mul() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Here's how to produce this message:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
parse_expr('zeta+1')
```

I think it's interpreting `zeta` as a function (the error message is unclear to me). I also tried setting `global_dict` as follows: `parse_expr('zeta+1', global_dict={})` but then this fails as it says `Symbol` is not defined. I can go through and add `Symbol` (and `Integer`) to my custom `global_dict`, and then it parses correctly, but this seems ugly to me (I would also need to add others to support general expressions, such as `Float`).

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SymPy, `zeta` means the Riemann zeta-function, so this is how your string is interpreted. But then `zeta + 1` is not a valid SymPy expression, since one cannot add a number to a function (`zeta(x) + 1` would have been accepted.)

Solution: use the `local_dict` parameter to tell SymPy what zeta really means here. Don't mess with `global_dict`; local takes precedence over global anyway.

```
from sympy import symbols
zeta = symbols('zeta')
parse_expr('zeta + 1', local_dict={'zeta': zeta})
```